# How many moments determine a normal distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

I know that a Gaussian distribuion is determined by its moments. I was wondering if there is a result of the form:

*if we know that the first thousand moments of a random variable are Gaussian, then is the distribution Gaussian?*

Comment: No such result exists. You may find a counterexample in the book "Counterexamples in Probability And Statistics" by Romano and Siegel (example 3.12).

Comment: By "the moments are Gaussian" do you mean "the moments agree with what they would be for a Gaussian"?

Comment: ......yes......